# Upload stop working suddenly ! move_uploaded_file problem

Tags: php, upload

I have a script on my server for uploading file. It is working fine before but suddenly it cannot upload files to the server. I did not change the code, I did not change anything related to php setting or directories permission also for the server. I did not change any thing in the webserver (apache). I created a small script to isolate the problem but I did not get any error messages or warning. The script are the following:

---

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$target_path = "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/userfiles3/2010-01-27/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
   echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
 } else{
   echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

Comment: What happens when you run your script? Can you show a dump of $_FILES?

Comment: The following is the ouput after adding var_dump($_FILES); 

    array(1) { ["uploadedfile"]=>  array(5) { ["name"]=>  string(12) "DSC00562.JPG" ["type"]=>  string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=>  string(0) "" ["error"]=>  int(2) ["size"]=>  int(0) } } There was an error uploading the file, please try again!

Comment: have you checked that the file doesn't exceed the upload limit (upload_max_filesize ini direcyive)?

Comment: It did not exceeded the size limit. It  is strange problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem on one of the servers I was working on; the problem there was, that the temporary directory where php was storing the uploaded files had reached its allocated limit and therefore couldn't fit anything else in there.

After cleaning the directory of obsolete files it was working again.

Answer (score 1):

According to your output:

```
var_dump($_FILES); 
array(1) { 
  ["uploadedfile"]=> array(5) { 
       ["name"]=> string(12) "DSC00562.JPG" 
       ["type"]=> string(0) "" 
       ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" 
       ["error"]=> int(2) 
       ["size"]=> int(0) 
  } 
}
```

The error 2 indicate that the field exceed the max filesize indicated into the html form 
as you can see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

You should check if in the form you use to upload the file there is something similar to

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="_a number_"/>
```

and remove it or specify a larger limit.

Comment: Eineki. Thanks for help. This is the problem with the small script that I wrote for test.
The original script get back to normal stat. now it can upload files without any problem! I did not change any thing

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but I had client-side problem. My Power Point Show (pps) file was corrupt. I re-saved with LibreOffice, and now my class-sharer script works!